# dynamic tabs that worked in Bootstrap 2 don't work in Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I've used the following successfully in Bootstrap 2.1 but when I try to use it in Bootstrap 3, the dynamic content isn't loaded.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Thanks

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
      $("#MainTabs").tab();
      $("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {    
        var contentID  = $(e.target).attr("data-target");
        var contentURL = $(e.target).attr("href");
        if (typeof(contentURL) != 'undefined')
      $(contentID).load(contentURL, function(){ $("#MainTabs").tab(); });
    else
      $(contentID).tab('show');
      });
      $('#MainTabs a:first').tab("show");
    });
    </script>
```

and

```
   <ul id="MainTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a data-target="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" href="a">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-target="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" href="content-test.php">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a data-target="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" href="tab-calendar.php?SiteID=201">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using....

```
$("#MainTabs").bind("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
```

Instead of...

```
$("#MainTabs").bind("show", function(e) {
```

Although as of jQuery 1.7, `.on()` is the preferred method for attaching event handlers.

```
$("#MainTabs").on("show.bs.tab", function(e) {
```

Comment: That's it - thanks very much for such a quick response!

Comment: No problem, please mark answers as correct, if it did in fact solve your issue.